# `docker logs foo | less` isn't searchable or scrollable but `docker logs foo 2>&1 | less` is

Tags: pipe, less, stdout, stderr

Using either one gives readable text.  But only with the stderr redirect can one scroll or type /somepattern and get matches.

Without it searching gives "Nothing to search (press RETURN)" and a column of ~'s.

Given, stderr and stdout aren't the same but why does less show them the same right up until I start doing something in less?

This maybe some weird multi-window vim thing that I just don't understand.  Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the searchable command alternative with 2>&1 before the pipe to less

Answer (score 10):

```
+--------------------+        +------+       +----------+
|             stdout |·······→| less |——————→|          |
| somecommand        |        +------+       | terminal |
|             stderr |——————————————————————→|          |
+--------------------+                       +----------+
```

If `somecommand` prints text to standard error only, then when you run `somecommand | less`, `somecommand` and `less` are both displaying to the terminal. The output of the command on its stderr isn't going to `less`, it's going to the terminal directly, since it isn't redirected. First the output of `somecommand` scrolls by while less initializes and shows its prompt line; then when `somecommand` finishes less notices that its input is complete (because the pipe is closed).
You may want to experiment a bit: run

```
{ sleep 1; somecommand; sleep 1; } | { sleep 0; less; }
```

and variations on the sleep times to have `somecommand` produce output before or after less is ready and to see what happens when the pipe is closed.